# Can't shut elementary OS down: cpu hard lockup

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, elementary-os, nouveau

I can't shut my system down. I have 5 sec timer for shutting down in systemd config and watchdog.
In journalctl i found several issues:

```
фев 19 10:14:40 denis-pc gnome-session-binary[1034]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
фев 19 10:14:40 denis-pc systemd[1]: Stopped watchdog daemon.
фев 19 10:14:40 denis-pc systemd[1]: watchdog.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
фев 19 10:14:40 denis-pc systemd[1]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Resource deadlock avoided
фев 19 10:14:40 denis-pc systemd[1]: watchdog.service: Failed to enqueue OnFailure= job: Resource deadlock avoided
фев 19 10:14:40 denis-pc gnome-session-binary[1034]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
фев 19 10:14:40 denis-pc gnome-session-binary[1034]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

And then i got this lockup on cpu message:

```
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 6
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 arc4 rtsx_usb_ms memstick iwlmvm mac80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_real
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq hid_generic rtsx_usb_sdmmc usbhid hid rtsx_usb nouveau i915 mxm_wmi ttm 
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: CPU: 6 PID: 831 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. GL63 8RD/MS-16P6, BIOS E16P6IMS.107 09/05/2018
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:ioread32+0x1e/0x40
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffbbd281b73728 EFLAGS: 00000096
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RAX: 00000000ffffffff RBX: ffff9c94278c0000 RCX: 0000000000000000
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffbbd284070000 RDI: ffffbbd284009410
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RBP: ffffbbd281b73728 R08: ffffffffc07531e0 R09: 0000000000000004
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: R10: ffffffffc0753140 R11: ffff9c94327c84e0 R12: ffff9c94278c0000
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: R13: ffff9c9427858ea0 R14: ffffffffffffffff R15: ffff9c9433855748
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: FS:  00007fed32f56600(0000) GS:ffff9c943dd80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: CR2: 000055ede85690c0 CR3: 000000026e218001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: Call Trace:
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nv04_timer_read+0x22/0x60 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_timer_read+0x15/0x20 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  g84_bar_flush+0x5f/0xe0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_bar_flush+0x1f/0x30 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nv50_instobj_release+0x2e/0xa0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  gp100_vmm_lpt_invalid+0x7c/0xd0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_vmm_unref_ptes+0x1e0/0x1f0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.13+0x24e/0x880 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? ktime_get+0x43/0xa0
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? gf100_vmm_pgt_dma+0x2f0/0x2f0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_put_region+0x160/0x160 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? quirk_increase_t12_delay+0x10/0x20 [i915]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_vmm_ptes_unmap_put+0x32/0x50 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? gf100_vmm_pgt_dma+0x2f0/0x2f0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_vmm_put_locked+0x103/0x220 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_uvmm_mthd+0x7d1/0x8d0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? ext4_inode_csum.isra.56+0x1a2/0x210
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_object_mthd+0x1a/0x30 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_ioctl_mthd+0x5d/0xb0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_ioctl+0x11d/0x280 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_client_ioctl+0x12/0x20 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvif_object_ioctl+0x47/0x50 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvif_object_mthd+0x129/0x150 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? find_get_entries+0x168/0x200
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? __slab_free+0x14d/0x2c0
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nvif_vmm_put+0x5f/0x80 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nouveau_vma_del+0x75/0xc0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nouveau_gem_object_close+0x1e3/0x230 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  drm_gem_object_release_handle+0x33/0x90 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  drm_gem_handle_delete+0x5e/0x90 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? drm_gem_handle_create+0x40/0x40 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  drm_gem_close_ioctl+0x20/0x30 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0x5f/0xb0 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x31b/0x3d0 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? drm_gem_handle_create+0x40/0x40 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x72/0xc0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x630
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? handle_mm_fault+0xb1/0x1f0
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  ? __do_page_fault+0x270/0x4d0
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fed3034b5d7
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffca146f788 EFLAGS: 00003246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055ede8567230 RCX: 00007fed3034b5d7
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RDX: 00007ffca146f7c0 RSI: 0000000040086409 RDI: 0000000000000010
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: RBP: 00007ffca146f7c0 R08: 0000000000000081 R09: 000055ede8a36c30
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: R10: 00007fed30620ca0 R11: 0000000000003246 R12: 0000000040086409
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000010 R14: 000055ede77e36a8 R15: ffffffffffffffff
фев 19 10:15:01 denis-pc kernel: Code: ff b8 ff ff 00 00 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 81 ff ff ff 03 00 48 89 e5 77 0f 48 81 ff 00 00 01 00 76 0a 0f b7 d7 ed 5d c3 8b 0
фев 19 10:15:05 denis-pc systemd[1]: acpid.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
фев 19 10:15:05 denis-pc systemd[1]: acpid.service: Killing process 721 (acpid) with signal SIGKILL.
фев 19 10:15:05 denis-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
фев 19 10:15:05 denis-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Killing process 824 (lightdm) with signal SIGKILL.
фев 19 10:15:05 denis-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Killing process 831 (Xorg) with signal SIGKILL.
фев 19 10:15:05 denis-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
фев 19 10:15:06 denis-pc systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
фев 19 10:15:06 denis-pc systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Killing process 732 (systemd-logind) with signal SIGKILL.
фев 19 10:15:31 denis-pc systemd[1]: acpid.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
фев 19 10:15:31 denis-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
фев 19 10:15:31 denis-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Killing process 831 (Xorg) with signal SIGKILL.
фев 19 10:15:31 denis-pc systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:         6-...0: (0 ticks this GP) idle=59e/140000000000000/0 softirq=7242/7242 fqs=7141 
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:         (detected by 1, t=15002 jiffies, g=6743, c=6742, q=6225)
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: Sending NMI from CPU 1 to CPUs 6:
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: NMI backtrace for cpu 6
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: CPU: 6 PID: 831 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. GL63 8RD/MS-16P6, BIOS E16P6IMS.107 09/05/2018
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RIP: 0010:ioread32+0x1e/0x40
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffbbd281b73728 EFLAGS: 00000092
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RAX: 00000000ffffffff RBX: ffff9c94278c0000 RCX: 0000000000000000
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffbbd284070000 RDI: ffffbbd284009400
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RBP: ffffbbd281b73728 R08: ffffffffc07531e0 R09: 0000000000000004
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: R10: ffffffffc0753140 R11: ffff9c94327c84e0 R12: 00000000ffffffff
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: R13: ffff9c9427858ea0 R14: ffffffffffffffff R15: ffff9c9433855748
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: FS:  00007fed32f56600(0000) GS:ffff9c943dd80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: CR2: 000055ede85690c0 CR3: 000000026e218001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: Call Trace:
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nv04_timer_read+0x35/0x60 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_timer_read+0x15/0x20 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  g84_bar_flush+0x5f/0xe0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_bar_flush+0x1f/0x30 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nv50_instobj_release+0x2e/0xa0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  gp100_vmm_lpt_invalid+0x7c/0xd0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_vmm_unref_ptes+0x1e0/0x1f0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.13+0x24e/0x880 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? ktime_get+0x43/0xa0
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? gf100_vmm_pgt_dma+0x2f0/0x2f0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_put_region+0x160/0x160 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? quirk_increase_t12_delay+0x10/0x20 [i915]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_vmm_ptes_unmap_put+0x32/0x50 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? gf100_vmm_pgt_dma+0x2f0/0x2f0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_vmm_put_locked+0x103/0x220 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_uvmm_mthd+0x7d1/0x8d0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? ext4_inode_csum.isra.56+0x1a2/0x210
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_object_mthd+0x1a/0x30 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_ioctl_mthd+0x5d/0xb0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_ioctl+0x11d/0x280 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvkm_client_ioctl+0x12/0x20 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvif_object_ioctl+0x47/0x50 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvif_object_mthd+0x129/0x150 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? find_get_entries+0x168/0x200
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? __slab_free+0x14d/0x2c0
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nvif_vmm_put+0x5f/0x80 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nouveau_vma_del+0x75/0xc0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nouveau_gem_object_close+0x1e3/0x230 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  drm_gem_object_release_handle+0x33/0x90 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  drm_gem_handle_delete+0x5e/0x90 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? drm_gem_handle_create+0x40/0x40 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  drm_gem_close_ioctl+0x20/0x30 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0x5f/0xb0 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x31b/0x3d0 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? drm_gem_handle_create+0x40/0x40 [drm]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x72/0xc0 [nouveau]
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x630
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? handle_mm_fault+0xb1/0x1f0
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  ? __do_page_fault+0x270/0x4d0
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fed3034b5d7
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffca146f788 EFLAGS: 00003246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055ede8567230 RCX: 00007fed3034b5d7
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RDX: 00007ffca146f7c0 RSI: 0000000040086409 RDI: 0000000000000010
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: RBP: 00007ffca146f7c0 R08: 0000000000000081 R09: 000055ede8a36c30
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: R10: 00007fed30620ca0 R11: 0000000000003246 R12: 0000000040086409
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: R13: 0000000000000010 R14: 000055ede77e36a8 R15: ffffffffffffffff
фев 19 10:15:40 denis-pc kernel: Code: ff b8 ff ff 00 00 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 81 ff ff ff 03 00 48 89 e5 77 0f 48 81 ff 00 00 01 00 76 0a 0f b7 d7 ed 5d c3 8b 0
фев 19 10:15:56 denis-pc systemd[1]: acpid.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
фев 19 10:15:56 denis-pc systemd[1]: acpid.service: Killing process 721 (acpid) with signal SIGKILL.
фев 19 10:15:56 denis-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
фев 19 10:15:56 denis-pc systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'
```

Is something wrong with nvidia drivers?

Comment: Actually, i found out that it happens on any OS (tried liveCD Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu). Arch without GUI seems to work fine. I had Arch with KDE before, it wasn't shutting down either, but it was without any Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Manual killing of lightdm (sudo service lightdm stop) makes the same lockups. And when i login in some tty while i have xorg in tty7 i got lockup too. It there a way to start OS in rEFInd without GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I tried to reinstall drivers, deleted nouveau. But the new errors kept coming. The problem was in ACPI. I guess, my computer has no ACPI support for Linux or something, that is why ALL Linux systems was broken (i am using notebook MSI GL63 8RD). In rEFInd you need to press F2 on elementary OS, then press it again on some menu entry. Here you need to write acpi=off somewhere (i guess, before initrd?) like this (remember or make a photo of your parameters, it may be useful to make a photo for single-user mod too):

```
ro root=UUID=71b3a0e8-7b30-44ce-8058-00ab43d17a00 acpi=off initrd=boot\initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic
```

If it works for you, you can make it permanent (you can, but do not do it in BIOS if you have Windows on your computer). Go to /boot of your Linux disk. Check if there is your initrd.img. Create file refind_linux.conf. Here you can write custom menu entries. **Be careful**, after rebooting you'll see ONLY the entries from this file, so be sure to have LiveCD to remove it in case of mistake. Write your custom entry like this (no need to write initrd since rEFInd find kernels automatically and uses the last versions):

```
"Boot using default options" "root=UUID=71b3a0e8-7b30-44ce-8058-00ab43d17a00 ro acpi=off"
```

You can copy UUID for disk from folder /dev/disk/by-uuid/:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

You also may want to create option for single-user mod or for outdated kernels from /boot, so you can just copy it from original rEFInd booted without refind_linux.conf. Hope it will work for you! :)

PS: When using a LiveCD you may find GRUB2 there. To boot from liveCD with ACPI off look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/160056).

PPS (after ~week of testing): Computer starts and shuts smoothly. But this solution will turn off the battery indicator in system (good thing if you have some hardware led), also your laptop will probably never go to sleep, it will just shut down suspended computer. After the shutdown i get the message "System halted" and then i must manually press the power button to turn the energy off. At least it works fine...

Actually, there is another way. I removed nouveau drivers and installed nvidia-driver-390 (last one at the moment). Looks like now i can run my laptop with ACPI. I think, it is a [known problem with MSI laptops](https://askubuntu.com/questions/734872/unable-to-run-ubuntu-on-a-msi-laptop-without-disabling-acpi).